# List comprehension from two different length lists ( [2 * n] and [2 * m] ) to one single list of [ 3 * len(unique(n[0],m[0])) ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Given lists:

```
a = [
 [2, 10  ],
 [3, 120],
 [4, 30 ]
]

b = [
 [1, 10 ],
 [2, 40]
]
```

How could I use list comprehension, zipping, min/max, join, enumerate, izip_longest, map, and/or lambda to return a third list that is ordered by the left variable, with duplicates of the left variable joined into a single row, maintaining the position of the original lists in the middle and last positions.  Assume `a` will always be in the middle position, and `b` will always be in the last position, as `a` and `b` may have varying lengths.

```
c = [
 [1, None, 10   ],
 [2, 10  , 40   ],
 [3, 120 , None ],
 [4, 30  , None ]
]
```

For one line copying/pasting

```
a = [[2, 0],[3, 120],[4, 30]]
b = [[1, 0],[2, 40]]
c = [[1, None, 0],[2, 0, 40],[3, 120 , None],[4, 30, None]]
```

Thanks for the help.   I'm getting lost trying after a coveted one-liner to help me understand the ways of thinking of python gurus!

Comment: I don't understand why `None` is in the middle for `[1, None, 10   ]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i assume cuz `a` does not have `a` `1` in it and `b` does

Comment: I also assume that op wants the first element of each `a` and `b` list to be the start of the `c` list, with the rest of the values of  `a` first then `b` and if there's no value then set None.

Comment: I cannot use `sum` here, not answering (that's a private joke, sorry)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre @MooingRawr, Yes that is correct.   Since there is no corresponding value in the original lists (`a` or `b`), in the final list `None` is included.    This can be read vertically downward in the middle column as `a`'s values, where `None` means there is no corresponding shared value to any `b` value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a chain-map + list comprehension:

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> c = ChainMap(dict(a), dict(b))
>>> [[k] + [d.get(k) for d in c.maps] for k in c]
[[1, None, 0], [2, 0, 40], [3, 120, None], [4, 30, None]]
```

It will easily generalize to using more than 2 input lists this way.

Comment: with `ChainMap(*map(dict,(a,b)))` ? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind creating throwaway dicts, something like:

```
da = dict(a)
db = dict(b)

cc = [[k, da.get(k), db.get(k)] for k in sorted(set(da) | set(db))]
```

seems to work (for your example, at least).

- The dicts allow you to "find" rows by the first element
- The `sorted(set(da) | set(db))` takes the sorted intersection of the the keys of the two dictionaries `da` and `db`.
- By using `dict.get` we can handle the case where the row doesn't exist gracefully.  (`dict.get` has a default default of `None`, so we don't need to provide it, but you could if you wanted to.)

Comment: np this answer could be shorter & clearer if it didn't repeat the working code

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame(dict(a),index=[0]).T
B = pd.DataFrame(dict(b),index=[0]).T
C = A.join(B,how='outer',lsuffix='l').reset_index().values
C
array([[  1.,  nan,  10.],
       [  2.,  10.,  40.],
       [  3., 120.,  nan],
       [  4.,  30.,  nan]])
```

If that is not enough, and you want `None` instead of `nan`, then you can do:

```
pd.np.where(pd.np.isnan(C),None,C).tolist()
[[1.0, None, 10.0], [2.0, 10.0, 40.0], [3.0, 120.0, None], [4.0, 30.0, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 - convert to dicts and perform dict merge**

```
a = [[2, 0],[3, 120],[4, 30]]
b = [[1, 0],[2, 40]]

a_dict = dict(a)
b_dict = dict(b)
merged = [
    (key, a_dict.get(key), b_dict.get(key))
    for key in sorted(a_dict.keys() | b_dict.keys())]
```

**Approach 2 - merging sorted lists**

This algorithm should be faster, but works only if both lists are sorted by the key value.

```
a = [[2, 0],[3, 120],[4, 30]]
b = [[1, 0],[2, 40]]

merged = []
a_pos, b_pos = 0, 0
while a_pos < len(a) and b_pos < len(b):
    assert a_pos == 0 or a[a_pos][0] >= a[a_pos-1][0]
    assert b_pos == 0 or b[b_pos][0] >= b[b_pos-1][0]
    if a[a_pos][0] == b[b_pos][0]:
        merged.append((a[a_pos][0], a[a_pos][1], b[b_pos][1]))
        a_pos += 1
        b_pos += 1
    elif a[a_pos][0] < b[b_pos][0]:
        merged.append((a[a_pos][0], a[a_pos][1], None))
        a_pos += 1
    else:
        merged.append((b[b_pos][0], None, b[b_pos][1]))
        b_pos += 1

while a_pos < len(a):
    merged.append((a[a_pos][0], a[a_pos][1], None))
    a_pos += 1

while b_pos < len(b):
    merged.append((b[b_pos][0], None, b[b_pos][1]))
    b_pos += 1

print(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([
[2, 10  ],
[3, 120],
[4, 30 ]
])

b = np.array([
[1, 10 ],
[2, 40]
])

index_a=a[:,0]
value_a=a[:,1]
index_b=b[:,0]
value_b=b[:,1]
df=pd.DataFrame({"index":index_a,"a":value_a})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"index":index_b,"b":value_b})
result=pd.merge(df,df2,on="index",how="outer")
result.set_index('index',inplace=True)
result.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(result)
```

output:

```
         a     b
index             
1        NaN  10.0
2       10.0  40.0
3      120.0   NaN
4       30.0   NaN

print(result.to_numpy())

[[ nan  10.]
[ 10.  40.]
[120.  nan]
[ 30.  nan]]
```